# Angular 16 provideClientHydration isStable NGRX Actions cause isStable to be false indefinitely

Tags: angular, ngrx, server-side-rendering

I was wondering is this the desired result of Angular 16 SSR or an issue with ClientHydration?

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
      animations: [slider],
      changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
    })
    export class IndexPageComponent implements OnInit {

      public authUser$: Observable<AuthUserModel | null | undefined> =
          this.AuthUserSvc.selectedCurrent$();

      public user$: Observable<UserModel | null> = this.AuthUser$.pipe(
          switchMap((authUser) =>
              this.UserSvc.selectedCurrent$()
          )
      );

      constructor(
          @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformID: object,
          private AuthUserSvc: AuthUserService,
          private UserSvc: UserService,
          private FriendSvc: FriendService,
          private RolesSvc: RolesService,
          private UserRolesSvc: UserRolesService,
          private AppRef: ApplicationRef
      ) {}

      async ngOnInit() {
        const user = await firstValueFrom(
            this.AuthUserSvc.selectedCurrent$().pipe(
                switchMap((authUser) =>
                    this.userSvc.selectById$(authUser?.selected_user_id)
                )
            )
        );

        if (user) {
          this.FriendSvc.readByIdsAPI({ user_ids: [user._id] });
          this.UserRolesSvc.readByIdsAPI( [user._id]);
          this.RolesSvc.readByUserAPI();
        } else {
          this.RolesSvc.readByUserAPI();
        }
      }
    }

    prepareRoute() {
      return this.contexts.getContext('primary')?.route?.snapshot?.data?.[
          'animation'
          ];
    }
}
```

Friend, Role, UserRole Service example.

```
public readByIdsAPI(obj: UserIdsRequestModel): void {
    this.store.dispatch(FriendActions.getByIdsAPI({ obj }))
}
```

This code will run but will not allow this.AppRef.isStable() will return false if you the following code is in. This is ngrx actions inside services.

```
if (user) {
    this.FriendSvc.readByIdsAPI({ user_ids: [user._id] });
    this.UserRolesSvc.readByIdsAPI( [user._id]);
    this.RolesSvc.readByUserAPI();
} else {
    this.RolesSvc.readByUserAPI();
}
```

If we remove this this dispatch action this.AppRef.isStable() will return true. note this is a Observable.